# Starting WinForm application where I can access first form

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to open a new form that would modify something on the first form, but since that original form was invoked by `Application.Run(new TestForm());`, it was inaccessible

I am wondering if what i've done is the best practice, here's my code

```
static class Program
{
    public static TestForm MainForm { get; private set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        using (Program.MainForm = new TestForm())
            Application.Run(Program.MainForm);                        
    }
}
```

TestForm class has a label

```
partial class TestForm
{        
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.outputLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.buttonOpenInput = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // outputLabel
        // 
        this.outputLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        this.outputLabel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.outputLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.outputLabel.Name = "outputLabel";
        this.outputLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259, 75);
        this.outputLabel.TabIndex = 0;
        this.outputLabel.Text = "label1";
        // 
        // buttonOpenInput
        // 
        this.buttonOpenInput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 108);
        this.buttonOpenInput.Name = "buttonOpenInput";
        this.buttonOpenInput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.buttonOpenInput.TabIndex = 1;
        this.buttonOpenInput.Text = "Set Text";
        this.buttonOpenInput.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonOpenInput.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonOpenInput_Click);
        // 
        // TestForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonOpenInput);
        this.Controls.Add(this.outputLabel);
        this.Name = "TestForm";
        this.Text = "Windows Form Test";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private Label outputLabel;
    private Button buttonOpenInput;

    public string OutputText
    {
        get { return this.outputLabel.Text; }
        set { this.outputLabel.Text = value; }
    }        
}
```

}

There's also a button

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{

    private InputForm iForm;

    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonOpenInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iForm = new InputForm();
        iForm.Show();            
    }
}
```

In that new InputForm there is a text box, with an accept button

```
private void buttonInputAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = richTextBoxInput.Text;
        Program.MainForm.OutputText = text;            
        this.Close();
    }
```

Is this good practice, or is there another way I should be doing this? The text box -> label was just a simple example, I might want to query a db and put certain results in labels, rows to a data grid view, etc

Thanks

Comment: You can access the form from [`Application.OpenForms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Looks fine to me - there is no real best practise here.